# trying to update signature of a message to be sent

Tags: outlook-redemption

Trying to update signature of a message to be sent (named mailItem, was created by Outlook OOM)
Following code does not seem to work (PP3 is an existing signature)

```
Redemption.RDOSession rdosession = Redemption.RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();
Redemption.RDOMail rdomail = rdosession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(mailItem);
Redemption.RDOSignatures signatures = rdosession.Signatures;
signatures.Item("PP3").ApplyTo(rdomail, false);
rdomail.CopyTo(mailItem);
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Do you have any issues if you create a new `RDOMail` instance from scratch? Is your mail item saved?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean mailItem does not see the change? This is to be expected as Outlook does not know it needs to refresh.
Try to create an item from the scratch using Redemption, apply the signature, and only then open it in Outlook using `Namespace.GetItemFromID`

Comment: Exactly, this is why this seems weird to me.
Cannot create by Redemption (was create by another plugin).Will try however in another project and keep you informed. Thanks for the hint.